# RoR Gemfile issue on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, rubygems, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've been struggling AWS-Elastic Beanstalk problems.
The other day, I appended some gems into Gemfile and then used `eb deploy`.
(Maybe the gem is whenever? or bcrypt? Sorry not sure)

It didn't work correctly on my deployment. The results are below.

```
ERROR: [Instance: i-452520da] Command failed on instance. Return code: 10 Output: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/10_reload_cron.sh: line 3: cd: HOME not set
Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory. 
Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/10_reload_cron.sh failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
INFO: Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
ERROR: Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-452520da'. Aborting the operation.
ERROR: Failed to deploy application.
```

Here's eb-activity.log.

```
[2016-08-28T01:51:16.844Z] INFO  [20749] - [Application update app-ed0b6-160828_104745@147/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployEnactHook] : Completed activity. Result:
  Successfully execute hooks in directory /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact.
[2016-08-28T01:51:16.844Z] INFO  [20749] - [Application update app-ed0b6-160828_104745@147/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployPostHook] : Starting activity...
[2016-08-28T01:51:16.844Z] INFO  [20749] - [Application update app-ed0b6-160828_104745@147/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployPostHook/01_create_pids.sh] : Starting activity...
[2016-08-28T01:51:17.044Z] INFO  [20749] - [Application update app-ed0b6-160828_104745@147/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployPostHook/01_create_pids.sh] : Completed activity.
[2016-08-28T01:51:17.044Z] INFO  [20749] - [Application update app-ed0b6-160828_104745@147/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployPostHook/10_reload_cron.sh] : Starting activity...
[2016-08-28T01:51:17.242Z] INFO  [20749] - [Application update app-ed0b6-160828_104745@147/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployPostHook/10_reload_cron.sh] : Activity execution failed, because: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/10_reload_cron.sh: line 3: cd: HOME not set
  Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory (ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError)
caused by: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/10_reload_cron.sh: line 3: cd: HOME not set
  Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)


[2016-08-28T01:51:17.242Z] INFO  [20749] - [Application update app-ed0b6-160828_104745@147/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployPostHook/10_reload_cron.sh] : Activity failed.
[2016-08-28T01:51:17.243Z] INFO  [20749] - [Application update app-ed0b6-160828_104745@147/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployPostHook] : Activity failed.
[2016-08-28T01:51:17.243Z] INFO  [20749] - [Application update app-ed0b6-160828_104745@147/AppDeployStage1] : Activity failed.
[2016-08-28T01:51:17.243Z] INFO  [20749] - [Application update app-ed0b6-160828_104745@147] : Completed activity. Result:
  Application update - Command CMD-AppDeploy failed
[2016-08-28T01:52:38.630Z] INFO  [2486]  - [CMD-TailLogs] : Starting activity...
[2016-08-28T01:52:38.630Z] INFO  [2486]  - [CMD-TailLogs/AddonsBefore] : Starting activity...
```

How could I eliminate this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I can work out this problem.
The thing is "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/10_reload_cron.sh".
So I deleted this file by using .ebextensions/some.sh